# Docker Windows | Unable to link directories between host and container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to link my Documents Folder on my host (which has a space in the name), with a directory in the host (also has a space in the name). I tried multiple method to run the container, but always end up with the error `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase`.

These are some of the commands I tried in order to run the container.

```
docker run -it --name=encee-flask-app -p 80:5000 -d -v E:\Documents\Encee Outputs:/home/Encee\ Outputs/ rapidcompiler/encee-image:latest

docker run -it --name=encee-flask-app -p 80:5000 -d -v E:/Documents/Encee\ Outputs:/home/Encee\ Outputs/ rapidcompiler/encee-image:latest

docker run --name=encee-flask-app -p 80:5000 -v 'E:/Documents/Encee':'/home/Encee Outputs' rapidcompiler/encee-image:latest

docker run --name=encee-flask-app -v 'E:/Documents/Encee':'/home/Encee\ Outputs' -p 80:5000 rapidcompiler/encee-image:latest
```

None of these work. They all throw the same error mentioned above. I presume this has something to do with the space I have in the folder names. How do I work around this?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the paths in `"` or `'`? Another option is to escape the spaces

Comment: docker run -it --name=encee-flask-app -p 80:5000 -d -v "E:\Documents\Encee Outputs:/home/Encee Outputs/" rapidcompiler/encee-image:latest

(Quotes over complete mount and not on each path)

Comment: @ThomasBrüggemann Thank you so much! That worked.